# How to make *ngFor filter out duplicate month and year from date in angular 2?

Tags: json, angular, date, angular-pipe

I have JSON array object which contains dates. I want to get displayed unique Month and Year(ignore day)from date. Please find my JSON object as below:

```
    {
"records"[
    {  
        "id":"833599",
        "date":1507624517000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"828140",
        "date":1506346215000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"817349",
        "date":1504852602000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"817347",
        "date":1504851799000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"817346",
        "date":1504851689000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"811693",
        "date":1504086405000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"721986",
        "date":1501140629000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"673227",
        "date":1499435543000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"673196",
        "date":1499433640000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"673190",
        "date":1499433410000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"673188",
        "date":1499433170000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"673171",
        "date":1499432516000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"672075",
        "date":1499336767000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"642516",
        "date":1498122509000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"632547",
        "date":1497350369000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"632546",
        "date":1497350336000,

     },
     {  
        "id":"632545",
        "date":1497350257000,

     },
     {  
        "id":"632543",
        "date":1497350221000,

     },
     {  
        "id":"631750",
        "date":1497256103000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"624957",
        "date":1496820632000, 
     },
     {  
        "id":"621103",
        "date":1496237026000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"620648",
        "date":1496220870000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"613655",
        "date":1495813509000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"610014",
        "date":1495617958000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"609984",
        "date":1495601967000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"603345",
        "date":1495188742000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"596499",
        "date":1494932889000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"596459",
        "date":1494914330000,
     },
     {  
        "id":"587822",
        "date":1494510858000,
     }
    ]
}
```

I want get output as below:

```
October 2017
September 2017
August 2017
July 2017
June 2017
May 2017
```

I tried to use

```
<div *ngFor="let record of records" class="month-row">
        <div class="month-name">{{ record.date | date: 'MMMM yyyy'}}</div>
</div>
```

But getting below result:

```
October 2017
September 2017
September 2017
September 2017
September 2017
August 2017
August 2017
July 2017
July 2017
July 2017
June 2017
May 2017
May 2017
May 2017
May 2017
```

Could you please help to get unique Month and year from this date so month    and year shouldn't be duplicate?

Also, Please note if year is different then month can be repeat.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867448/in-angular2-ngfor-iteration-how-do-i-output-only-unique-values-from-the-array Please review this answer.

Comment: Thank you! but I want get unique month as well as year(ignore day from date). In provided link we only get unique string. Can you please help?

Comment: You are missing " after let record of records

Comment: @Charlie, I have corrected that still not getting expected output.

Comment: where is dateGroup coming from and why record is not used from (record of records)

Comment: @Charlie, sorry it was typo mistake. Now corrected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display only unique values in the dropdown using Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38362047/how-to-display-only-unique-values-in-the-dropdown-using-angular-2)

Answer (score 4):

You need to create one pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'filterMonthYear' })
export class UniqueMonthYearPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(dates) {

    var updated_dates = dates.map(date => {
      var d = new Date(date.date);
      return (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear(); 
    });

    return Array.from(new Set(updated_dates));
  }
}
```

And use it like :

```
<div *ngFor="let record of (records.records | filterMonthYear)">
  {{record}}
</div>
```

---

Here is the link to working example :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-pipe

Comment: Thank you so much! I need one more help in my project which i can't explain without showing to you. Can you  please share your mobile number?

Comment: @vivekdoshi2, please help.

Comment: @PravinGojamgunde, I am bit busy for now,will check tomorrow

Comment: @vivekdoshi2, did u got the chance?

Comment: @vivekdoshi2, please do this on weekend.

Comment: @PravinGojamgunde, sure , will you please accept the answer , as your question is already solved ?

Comment: @vivekdoshi2, did you fixed my issue?

Comment: @PravinGojamgunde, man its big task need continues time to complete it and I am very busy with other things also