# How to stop getting redundant date in filter in angular 2

Tags: angular, date, datetime, angular2-routing, datetime-format

I am getting dates like this in my filter ...

Fri, 26 Sep 2014 17:00:00 GMT
Fri, 26 Sep 2014 18:30:00 GMT
Fri, 26 Sep 2014 22:30:00 GMT

While from database for filter I am getting three same dates like this ...

26-Sep-2014
26-Sep-2014
26-Sep-2014

But **I want Only one

26-Sep-2014**

So how can I achieve that ??

Comment: make use of moment and filter these dates

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048785/how-to-make-ngfor-filter-out-duplicate-month-and-year-from-date-in-angular-2?answertab=active#tab-top this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in component and loop through it (this will give you a rough idea how to do it)

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
  <p>{{test | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'}} - format: dd/MM/yyyy</p>`
})
export class AppComponent { 
  test : Date = new Date();
}
```

Here is the **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I8g9ybkHMXnGGEZ47nSQ?p=preview)**

**Edit it in component:** Create a function `getFormatDate()` and use it like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
  <p>{{getFormatDate(test) | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'}} - format: dd/MM/yyyy</p>`
})
export class AppComponent { 
  test : Date = new Date();
  getFormatDate(dte){
    return new Date(dte);
  }
}
```

Here is the **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I8g9ybkHMXnGGEZ47nSQ?p=preview)**

Comment: Can I set it directly in component ??  
Like using setDate()

Comment: @Aarsh now check my answer

Comment: Your answer is right , but I got my answer I will update it .

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is the perfect answer

```
  this.DeliveryDate = json.DateStart != null ? new Date(json.DateStart).setHours(0,0,0) : null;
```

By setHours(0,0,0) only one date will get as per my question.