# Angular2 removing duplicates from an JSON array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter, angular, ngfor

I have a problem with filter in my JSON array when I move my app to Angular2 . In Angular 1.x that was easier. I used `'unique'` in filter and this remove all duplicates.

apps:

```
{"app":"database_1",
 "host":"my_host1",
 "ip":"00.000.00.000"
},
{"app":"database_1",
 "host":"my_host1",
 "ip":"00.000.00.000"
},
{"app":"database_2",
 "host":"my_host2",
 "ip":"00.000.00.000"
},
{"app":"database_2",
 "host":"my_host2",
 "ip":"00.000.00.000"
}
```

Part of html code:

```
    <div *ngFor='#appsUnique of apps '>
        <div class="row dashboard-row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
               <h4>{{appsUnique.app }}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And result is:

```
database_1
database_1
database_2
database_2
```

I want to get result:

```
database_1
database_2
```

How can I remove duplicates from an array?

Comment: As in angular2 filters replaced by pipes and some filters not available in angular2. you can write custom @Pipe to filter array. and for array processing lodash js is also helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I found similar topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417250/filtering-an-array-in-angular2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a solution for this problem :)

```
Array.from(new Set([{"app":"database_1",
 "host":"my_host1",
 "ip":"00.000.00.000"
},
{"app":"database_1",
 "host":"my_host1",
 "ip":"00.000.00.000"
},
{"app":"database_2",
 "host":"my_host2",
 "ip":"00.000.00.000"
},
{"app":"database_2",
 "host":"my_host2",
 "ip":"00.000.00.000"
}].map((itemInArray) => itemInArray.app)))
```

[More about Array.from & Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Thanks all for help :)

Answer (score 11):

Mybe it can help you

```
myList = ["One","two","One","tree"];

myNewList =  Array.from(new Set(myList ));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use following method:

```
names = ["Mike","Matt","Nancy","Adam","Jenny","Nancy","Carl"];

ngOnInit() {
    let filteredNames=this.remove_duplicates(this.names);
    console.log(filteredNames);
    console.log(this.names);
}
remove_duplicates(arr) {
    let obj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        obj[arr[i]] = true;
    }
    arr = [];
    for (let key in obj) {
        arr.push(key);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Observable approach as well, It is very simple.

```
let filteredData = [];
let arrayData = [{
  "app": "database_1",
  "host": "my_host1",
  "ip": "00.000.00.000"
},
{
  "app": "database_1",
  "host": "my_host1",
  "ip": "00.000.00.000"
},
{
  "app": "database_2",
  "host": "my_host2",
  "ip": "00.000.00.000"
},
{
  "app": "database_2",
  "host": "my_host2",
  "ip": "00.000.00.000"
}];

Observable.merge(arrayData)
  .distinct((x) => x.app)
  .subscribe(y => {
    filteredData.push(y)
    console.log(filteredData)
  });
```

Comment: I too wanted to get unique objects from an array of objects by comparing a particular object variable. I tried all solutions available but only this one worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

instead of looping over the normal json array, you can create another array in your corresponding typescript class, and alter this as you see fit. In your html, you can then have the following

### html

```
 <div *ngFor='let appsUnique of filteredApps'>
    <div class="row dashboard-row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
           <h4>{{appsUnique.app }}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Next, you need this filteredApps array in your corresponding typescript class.

### typescript

```
 let filteredApps = [];
```

and in a function you can then create that filteredApps, for example in the `onInit` method.

```
onInit()
{
    filteredApps = // filter logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need [trackBy](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html).

Try with:

```
*ngFor="#appsUnique of posts;trackBy:appsUnique?.app"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried using trackBy, but couldn't achieve it. can u experiment here https://fiddle.jshell.net/1y0tw6zf/53/

Comment: trackBy was added in beta 3. Maybe you're using a previous version.
[tweet](https://twitter.com/angularjs/status/694963587157131264)

Comment: I have angular2-2.0.0-beta.15 and when i use your code (`*ngFor="#appsUnique of apps;trackBy:appsUnique?.app`), result is the same of at the beginnig.

Comment: You can see more deatils [here](http://angularjs.blogspot.co.at/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html)