# Find unique element in an array and the find the sum of field(say Marks) for the duplicate elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, angular5, lodash

This question may be similar to [In Angular2 *ngFor iteration, how do I output only unique values from the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867448/in-angular2-ngfor-iteration-how-do-i-output-only-unique-values-from-the-array/41867927) but my question is have some more features.

I have a list of the following form

```
    let studentsList = [{
        name:'A',
        rollNo:1,
        mark:10
    },
    {
        name:'B',
        rollNo:2,
        mark:30
    },
    {
        name:'C',
        rollNo:3,
        mark:40
    },
    {
        name:'A',
        rollNo:1,
        mark:50
    }
  ]
```

The objective is to display unique name and marks from the `studentList` and find the unique name from it like this.

```
A   10
B   30
C   40
```

Also if the name repeats then add the marks and display.

```
A   60
B   30
C   40
```

I could filter the unique names like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'lodash'; 

@Pipe({
  name: 'unique',
  pure: false
})

    export class UniquePipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(value: any): any{
            if(value!== undefined && value!== null){
                return _.uniqBy(value, 'name');
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
```

then in html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let student of studentList| unique">
    {{student .name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Edit

The `studentsList` is dynamic we can add as many details needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a result array of name and marks (sum of duplicates) then you can do that with a very cleaner way in lodash (since you tagged lodash). [_.groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) will always group it by its unique parameter and group all duplivates with that parameter inside a array for each group.

1. First, group it by `name` using [_.groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy)
2. Then map ([*.map*](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map)) each group and calculate sum of marks by [.sumBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sumBy)

Here is an working example:

```js
let input = [{"name":"A","rollNo":1,"mark":10},{"name":"B","rollNo":2,"mark":30},{"name":"C","rollNo":3,"mark":40},{"name":"A","rollNo":1,"mark":50}],
    res = _(input)
            .groupBy('name')
            .map((g, name) => ({name, mark: _.sumBy(g, 'mark')}))
            .value();
            
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function into your pipe:

```
value.reduce((acc, ele) => {
  const existingStudent = acc.find(x => x.name === ele.name);
  if(!existingStudent) return acc.concat(ele);
  return (existingStudent.mark += ele.mark, acc);
},[])
```

Testing it:

```js
var studentsList=[{name:"A",rollNo:1,mark:10},{name:"B",rollNo:2,mark:30},{name:"C",rollNo:3,mark:40},{name:"A",rollNo:1,mark:50}];

const resp = studentsList.reduce((acc, ele) => {
  const existingStudent = acc.find(x => x.name === ele.name);
  if(!existingStudent) return acc.concat(ele);
  return (existingStudent.mark += ele.mark, acc);
},[])

console.log(resp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the studentList is dynamic then will this work?

Comment: This code is destructive as it mutates the items in the input list. This ain't siutable for a pipe in angular. So better use it in the place where you load and store the data.

Comment: means no need to write pipe?

Comment: @AnandRaj *"means no need to write pipe?"* this means, when you do this right after you've loaded the data in your Controller, and store the array with the accumulated values, then you don't need a pipe that does this when rendering the data.

Answer (score 0):

An example how to accumulate your values.

```js
let studentsList = [
  { name: 'A', rollNo: 1, mark: 10 },
  { name: 'B', rollNo: 2, mark: 30 },
  { name: 'C', rollNo: 3, mark: 40 },
  { name: 'A', rollNo: 1, mark: 50 }
];

const byName = {};
for (var student of studentsList) {
  if (student.name in byName) {
    byName[student.name].mark += student.mark;
  } else {
    byName[student.name] = { ...student };
  }
}
console.log(Object.values(byName));
```

Comment: What does that 3 dots indicate? means ...?

Comment: @AnandRaj it is a spread operator. In this case, `{ ...student }` creates a shallow copy of `student` so that I don't mutate the student from the input-array when I do `byName[student.name].mark += student.mark`.

Answer (score 0):

You can group your student array on the roll number and add the marks of same roll number in an object accumulator. Using `array#values()` get all the values corresponding to the roll number.

```js
let studentsList = [{ name:'A', rollNo:1, mark:10 }, { name:'B', rollNo:2, mark:30 }, { name:'C', rollNo:3, mark:40 }, { name:'A', rollNo:1, mark:50 } ],
    uniqueStudents = Object.values(studentsList.reduce((r,{name, rollNo, mark}) => {
      r[rollNo] = r[rollNo] || {name, rollNo, total : 0};
      r[rollNo].total += mark;
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(uniqueStudents);
```