# ionic 2 error on pipe filter (TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined)

Tags: angular, ionic2

hello i am using `ionic 2( version released 2.0)` and `angular 2( version core 2.2.1)` trying to make a array pipe filter but its always shows error 
Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

```
import { Pipe ,PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
 @Pipe({ name: 'fetch', pure: false }) 
export class Search implements PipeTransform { 

 transform(items:Array, conditions:{[field:string]:any}):Array { 
   return items.filter(item => { for (let field in conditions) { 
       if (item[field] !== conditions[field]) { 
         return false; 
       } 
      } 
      return true; 
   }); 
 } 
}
```

**HTML**

```html
`<ion-content>
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="term" [showCancelButton]="true"></ion-searchbar> 
      <ion-grid class="category">
      <ion-row text-center wrap>
        <ion-col width-33 *ngFor="let d of total|fetch:term">
<p> {{d.name}} </p>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>`

JSON responce code in total array [{id:1 ,name:"abc" },{id:2 ,name:"xyz" }]
```

Comment: add the code to the question.. not comment..

Comment: i am creating an array search filter and its shows this error any way hows i can make array search filter in ionic 2

Comment: can you add the html side?

Comment: also  I think it should be `items:any[]` not `items:Array`

Comment: you can update the question..cant really view that code in comment section

Comment: updated html..my total array have value and i want to filter it

Comment: tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417250/filtering-an-array-in-angular2

Answer (score 0):

Trying to guess since your code isn't complete.

Are you using an http request to get your data? Because in that case you have to check items first in this way:

```
 if (items==null) {
        return null;
    }
```

the complete code:

```
transform(items: Array<any>, conditions: {[field: string]: any}): Array<any> {
    if (items==null) {
        return null;
    }

    return items.filter(item => {
        for (let field in conditions) {

            if (item[field] !== conditions[field]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

then in the html part, if you are trying to filter {{d.name}},according to your pipe i think you have to write something like this:

```
*ngFor="let d of total|fetch:{name:term}"
```

Hope this help

Comment: Error has gone but search result is not working..    JSON responce code in total array [{id:1 ,name:"abc" },{id:2 ,name:"xyz" }]