# get a particular item inside an array in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular view I defined a variable `data` which is like this:

```
[{"name":"science", count: 3},
 {"name":"action", count: 1},
 {"name":"thriller", count: 1},
 {"name":"article",  count: 1},
]
```

"
So in html file I want to get the count count value for name "science" or "article"

I tried like this:

```
 <span ng-repeat="item in data| filter: {name: "science"}"> 
    {{ item.count }} 

 </span>
```

but this gives nothing, I guess because of the filter. How can I do this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you're *actually* using Angular 4, that's completely wrong syntax. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm new to this so I'm still learning sorry for the confusion

Comment: Then spend some time learning it, e.g. run through the tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering an array in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417250/filtering-an-array-in-angular2)

Answer (score -1):

First of all you are mixing up with AngularJS (1.x) syntax, with Angular (2+) you should use `ngFor` and a *custom pipe* for filtering.

```
 <span> <tr *ngFor="item in data  | sciencefilter:'science'"> {{ item.count }} </span>
```

and your filter should be

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'sciencefilter'
})
@Injectable()
export class ScienceFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], type: string): any {
        return items.filter(item => item.id.indexOf(type) !== -1);
    }
}
```

**WITHOUT USING FILTER**

```
count :number;
```

and then,

```
this.count = this.items.filter(t=>t.name ==='science');
```

and in component

```
 <span> 
    {{ count.length }}
 </span>
```

Comment: but I want to get the count value for a specific element not in a for loop

Comment: @pinks which element?

Comment: if "name":"science"

Comment: look at the example above

Comment: can I have direct access on array without using filter

Comment: `angular2/core`? Wow that is old.

Comment: If name ==='science' doesn't exists it throw an error is there any way to prevent it so if there's no find, to make it 0? thanks for your help

Comment: Yes you can add an if condition if(item.length == 0) assign count   as 0

Comment: No I want to use the second method this.count = this.items.filter(t=>t.name ==='science');

Comment: Did you sort it out

Answer (score -1):

You can use pipe like this -

```
import {Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myfilter'
})
@Injectable()
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
        return items.filter(item => item.id.indexOf(args[0]) !== -1);
    }
}
```

And the template would look like this -

```
*ngFor="let element of (elements | myfilter:'123')"
```

Comment: I get this error " Cannot find name 'PipeTransform'"

Comment: Please go through the documentation. The example might have some bugs as it was not tested before posting. It will just help you providing the idea about the answer. Updating the answer anyway.