# *ngIf string is exist - ionic/angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
<div id="sections" *ngFor="let section of clothesListArr?.addNewClothes">
    <h5>{{section.add_Sections}}</h5>
</div>
```

I want to write an if statement inside `<h5>` to check if the string is already exist 'printed', if it's exist I want to skip it and print the next one, so I don't have a duplicate value

Comment: You can get a better aproach: reduce your array to store uniques values, see, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417250/filtering-an-array-in-angular2